# Always calling DefaultPolicy handler in dotnet core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

So I have recently discovered, to my surprise, that if you apply an `[Authorize]` attribute with a custom policy, dotnet core no longer ensures that the user is authenticated, it is up to your new handler to do this instead.

This sort of makes sense, although it seems easy to get that wrong but I can't find the neatest way to ensure that any action that is NOT marked as `[Annoymous]` requires authentication before the custom policy is applied.

- If I add a global filter, in `AddMvc()`, it applies to all actions, even those that are marked as `Annoymous`
- If I make a call to check the user is authenticated in all custom handlers, this is brittle, it would easy to forget to do this
- Same concern with creating a base-class handler, there is not necessarily an easy way to ensure that a new handler inherits from the base class without some custom checking code.

Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure but if you can refer to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1#require-authenticated-users-1)?

Comment: That won't work since it doesn't apply to any actions that have an authorize attribute, whereas I want to apply the default + the policy if there is no "Anonnymous" attribute

Comment: I'm afraid it is the expected behavior since you set the custom policy as I didn't find any document to explain how to realize your requirement.